# How do I use task manager on a MAC using a PC Keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

Basically how do I 'control, alt, delete' But with a MAC computer, but using a Microsoft Keyboard? What other short cuts are there, like for instance, 'Alt F4' or 'Alt tab' but with a Microsoft keyboard.

Comment: Umm... The shortcuts are different for the OSs. You'll have to learn them, individually. Only third-party apps, and basic shortcuts like cut, copy, paste are similar. The task manager is called Activity Monitor in Mac; find using Spotlight or in `/Applications/Utilities/`, but if you just wanna quit an app do Cmd + Alt + Esc.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Mac doesn't have a Task Manager, as @user14492 explained, but knowing what you actually want to be able to do would really help us answer your question. You can edit your post with the button right underneath to explain further.

Comment: The question is five years old, the OP never bothered to come back and improve the question after posting it. So we could only guess whether the issue was about finding those shortcuts, about using them with a Microsoft/Windows keyboard, or something else altogether. The answers are helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, the equivalent to Task Manager is the **Activity Monitor**.

1. From the **Dock**, click the **Launchpad** icon, then search for and click **Activity Monitor**.

Alternatively, assuming that the Windows key behaves like the **[Cmd]** key, you can use **[Cmd+Space]**, then type **Activity Monitor**.

However, for applications that need to be force closed, right-click that application in the **Dock**, press **[Alt]** and choose **Force Quit**.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts are different for the OSs. You'll have to learn them, individually. Only third-party apps, and basic shortcuts like cut, copy, paste are similar. If you have a Win keyboard then the Win key is equal to Cmd (⌘) key, and rest are the same. Generally Win key is replaced with Cmd key in shortcuts.

The task manager is called Activity Monitor in Mac; find using Spotlight or in `/Applications/Utilities/` folder, but if you just wanna quit an app do Cmd + Alt + Esc (this can also be accessed through Apple () menu at the top).

I believe that Alt (⎇) + F4 quit an app on Win, so it's equivalent would be Cmd + Q. The Alt + Tab shortcut is the same as Cmd + Tab, or Cmd + Shft +Tab. Functions keys are rarely used and they have their pre-defined actions which you can see on a Mac keyboard. You can configure them to use as Standard functions key in the Keyboard Preference Pane.

You can see all the app shortcuts in the menus in the menu bar. The System shortcuts can be seem at System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts. You can also change them to what you like. If you find yourself using shortcuts but cannot remember them all I would recommend [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/), it shows all the possible shortcuts by pressing one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "activity monitor", there's another option that comes handy to close running apps --> "Force Quit Applications";

"Force Quit Applications" is launched by pressing Cmd (⌘) + Option (⌥) + Escape keys;

A List of running apps appear, where by you can select the necessary application from the list and force quit using the "Force Quit" button.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201276

Answer (score 0):

Just press Alt + (Windows Logo Key) + Esc.